# Почему не устанавливается библиотека retro?

Tags: python

Почему не устанавливается библиотека? Когда я её инсталлирую с помощью pip она мне выдаёт ошибку "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Retro (from versions: 0.9.5, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.8.5, 2.8.6, 2.8.7, 2.9.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Retro". Что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас не установлена ни одна из необходимых версий Python. Они приведены в скобках после слов from versions. Судя по всему, библиотека Retro создана для Python 2 и уже не поддерживается

Comment: А какую мне тогда использовать по аналогии?