# Есть ли другая по аналогии retro библиотека на Python 3.X?

Tags: python-3.x

Есть ли такая же библиотека как и retro, только на Python 3.X? Я просто скопировал код для игры "Sonic the Hedgehog" и там была библиотека retro но она для Python 2.X, и я не могу найти подходящую библиотеку, чтобы заменить её. Подскажите на какую библиотеку заменить?

```
import retro
import numpy as np
import cv2
import neat
import pickle

env = retro.make(game="TMNT", state="Zone 1. Sewerage")

config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction, neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                     'config-feedforward')

for genome_id, genome in genomes:
    ob = env.reset()
    ac = env.action_space.sample()

inx, iny, inc = env.observation_space.shape
inx = int(inx / 8)
iny = int(iny / 8)

net = neat.nn.recurrent.RecurrentNetwork.create(genome, config)

current_max_fitness = 0
fitness_current = 0
frame = 0
counter = 0
xpos = 0
done = False

env.render()
frame += 1
ob = cv2.resize(ob, (inx, iny))
ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ob = np.reshape(ob, (inx, iny))

imgarray = []
imgarray = np.ndarray.flatten(ob)
nnOutput = net.activate(imgarray)

ob, rew, done, info = env.step(nnOutput)

xpos = info['x']

if xpos >= 10000:
    fitness_current += 10000
    done = True

fitness_current += rew
if fitness_current > current_max_fitness:
    current_max_fitness = fitness_current
    counter = 0
else:
    counter += 1

if done or counter == 250:
    done = True
    print(genome_id, fitness_current)

genome.fitness = fitness_current

p = neat.Population(config)
p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
p.add_reporter(stats)
p.add_reporter(neat.Checkpointer(1))
winner = p.run(eval_genomes)
with open('winner.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(winner, output, 1)
```

Comment: Есть вот такая https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html но там нет `TMNT`, а вот `Sonic` там есть.

Comment: @CrazyElf, та библиотека, похоже, может эмулировать игры, но не уверен, что в комплекте с библиотекой что-то из них будет присутствовать :) **UPD.** а не есть: `"Airstriker-Genesis has a non-commercial ROM that is included by default."` и `env = retro.make(game='Airstriker-Genesis')`

Comment: @gil9red Ну там список довольно большой выдаётся по `import retro; retro.data.list_games()`, хотя я может чего не понял )

Comment: @CrazyElf, моя ошибка :)

Comment: Вот как переделать код Sonic под код для TMNT сделать?

Comment: Если игры нет в списке то надо дальше разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из [прошлого вашего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436692/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-retro), можно предположить, что вы перепутали название библиотеки.

Чтобы установить [нужную вам библиотеку](https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) необходимо, нужно прописать

```
pip install gym-retro
```

Comment: Ну я установил и что дальше?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вам нужно

Comment: А возможно переделать этот код под другую игру?

Comment: Скорее всего нет

Comment: А какая библиотека подойдет для ии чтобы он проходил  игры